# Download Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I installed Kali Linux 64 bit Virtual Box inside Oracle Virtual Box 5.0.20 for Windows hosts. It seems Kali Linux 64 bit Virtual Box is the same as Kali Linux.

I also downloaded Kali Linux 2016.1 64 bit ISO (`2.6G, SHA1Sum is deaa41c5c8f26b7854cafb34b6f1b567871c4875`). Do I need to install the ISO DVD?

My goal is to install Kali Linux 64 bit inside Oracle VirtualBox 5.0.20.

Answer (score 1):

Kali Linux 64 bit Virtual Box is actually a pre-configured Virtual Box file.
Kali Linux 2016.1 64 bit ISO is the installation image for Kali.

To be clear, the Virtual Box version is basically a file that you open with Virtual Box, the ISO version is a file that you burn on a DVD, or `dd` on a USB key so you can install your operating system on a machine.

So the answer is NO: you don't have to use the ISO to create a Kali virtual machine if you already have a virtual box package.